# How to get max CPU clock in Java

Tags: java, cpu

with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

I can get the numbers of CPU avaiable.

But how can I get their clock frequency?

*I was searching for a os-indipendent solution.*

Comment: This is OS-specific. Which OS are you running ?

Comment: Probably only platform-specific solutions exist (read /proc/cpuinfo?). But in general - it's not easy to tell the freq anymore... do you mean the current frequency? or the max frequency? and what about not limited VMs sharing a host with max 4GHz? (do 4 such hosts have 4GHz, or 1GHz each? or maybe the current idle value of 80MHz)

Comment: I don't know what you want to use this information for, but note that the clock frequency does not correspond to how fast the processor can do computations. A 3 GHz Pentium 4 for example is slower than a 2.4 GHz Core 2 Duo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no feature available in the [Java SE API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) which will return the frequency of the CPU.

Also, the [`Runtime.availableProcessors`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors()) method returns the number of processors available to the Java virtual machine at the time the method is called, so it won't necessarily return the number of actual processors in a system.

From the Java API Specification for the [`Runtime.availableProcessors`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors()) method:

> Returns the number of processors
>   available to the Java virtual machine.
>
> This value may change during a
>   particular invocation of the virtual
>   machine. Applications that are
>   sensitive to the number of available
>   processors should therefore
>   occasionally poll this property and
>   adjust their resource usage
>   appropriately.

In order to obtain such information, most likely, one would have to make calls the operating system using native calls via [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) (JNI).

Comment: Thank's. Very clear. I was searching for native method, but if doesn't exist I will study JNI. ;)

Comment: This is not intended to model the underlying hardware exactly but to give a rough idea of the number of concurrent threads the hardware can support.